# Adding an attribute in each iteration through `_set` in Django

Tags: python, django, attributes, django-queryset

I have a situation similar to this:

```
# models

class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Member(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey('common.Entity', help_text="FKey relationship to Entity table")
    name = models.TextField()


# view

def details(request, eid):
    entity = Entity.objects.select_related().get(id=eid)

    entity.entity_test = 'oh yeah'
    for member in entity.member_set.all():
        member.member_test = 'oh noes'

    response = {
        'entity': entity,
    }
    return render_to_response(
        'common/details.html',
        {'response': response},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )


# html template

visible -> {{ response.entity.entity_test }}<br />
{% for member in response.entity.member_set.all %}
    not visible -> {{ member.member_test }}  <!-- WHY? -->
{% endfor %}
```

So, how can I set an attribute here to each of my `member` so I can use it in the template?

Comment: Why not add a property to the model?

Comment: Hm, honestly, I was thinking about that but wasn't sure if I can pass some params to model's property (like I pass `eid` to view function in my case)

Comment: Return a function from the property and pass the argument to that.

Comment: Ah yeah, I see... Will try that! Thanks for tip, I accepted alecxe's answer since it is strictly related with question, but upvote for you too =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not modifying a `member_set` in the loop. Store the result of the `entity.member_set.all()` in the list variable and then modify it's items in the loop:

```
entity_members = entity.member_set.all()
for member in entity_members:
    member.member_test = 'oh noes'

response = {
        'entity': entity,
        'entity_members': entity_members
    }
```

Then, in the template:

```
{% for member in entity_members %}
    {{ member.member_test }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Hope that helps.